# Is there a way and how can i make the program increment the obstacleSpeed by one every time the score increments by one?

Tags: c#

Is there a way and how can i make the program increment the obstacleSpeed by one every time the score increments by one? (The part with all the if statements). Im thinking it must be some sort of for-loop, but maybe im all wrong. hope someone can help.

I am new at coding so it would be great if you could explain it on like kids level

My Program:

```
namespace Arnold
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool jumping = false;
        int jumpSpeed;
        int force = 15;
        int score = 0;
        int obstacleSpeed = 15;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int posisition;
        bool isGameOver = false;

 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GameReset();
        }

        private void mainGameTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Top += jumpSpeed;

            txtScore.Text = "score: " + score;

            if (jumping == true && force < 0)
            {
                jumping = false;
            }

            if (jumping == true)
            {
                jumpSpeed = -25;
                force -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                jumpSpeed = 25;
            }

            if (player.Top > 364 && jumping == false)
            {
                force = 15;
                player.Top = 365;
                jumpSpeed = 0;

            }
            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "Heli")
                {
                    x.Left -= obstacleSpeed;


                    if (x.Left < -100)
                    {
                        x.Left = this.ClientSize.Width + rand.Next(200, 500) + (x.Width * 15);
                    }

                    if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                    {
                        gameTimer.Stop();
                        player.Image = Properties.Resources.Explosion_2_0;
                        txtScore.Text += " Press R to restart the game! Or press Q to exit!";
                        isGameOver = true;
                    }
                }

                if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "obstacle")
                {
                     x.Left -= obstacleSpeed;
                    
                   
                    if (x.Left < -100)
                    {
                        x.Left = this.ClientSize.Width + rand.Next(200, 500) + (x.Width * 15);
                        score++;
                    }

                    if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                    {
                        gameTimer.Stop();
                        player.Image = Properties.Resources.Explosion_2_0;
                        txtScore.Text += " Press R to restart the game! Or press Q to exit!";
                        isGameOver = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (score > 5)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 20;
            }

            if(score > 10)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 25;
            }

            if (score > 15)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 30;
            }
            if (score > 20)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 35;
            }
            if (score > 25)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 40;
            }
            if (score > 30)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 45;
            }
            if (score > 35)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 50;
            }
            if (score > 40)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 55;
            }
            if (score > 45)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 60;
            }
            if (score > 50)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 65;
            }
            if (score > 55)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 70;
            }
            if (score > 60)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 75;
            }
            if (score > 65)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 80;
            }
            if (score > 70)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 85;
            }
            if (score > 75)
            {
                obstacleSpeed = 90;
            }
        }

        private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && jumping == false)
            {
                jumping = true;
            }
        }

        private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (jumping == true)
            {
                jumping = false;    
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.R && isGameOver == true)
            {
                GameReset();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q && isGameOver == true)
            {
                txtScore.Text = "Are you sure you want to exit the program? (Y/N)";
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Y)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.N)
            {
                GameReset();
            }
        }

        private void GameReset()
        {
            force = 15;
            jumpSpeed = 0;
            jumping = false;
            score = 0;
            obstacleSpeed = 15;
            txtScore.Text = "Score" + score;
            player.Image = Properties.Resources.figur_færdig;
            isGameOver = false;
            player.Top = 365;

            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                
                if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "obstacle")
                {
                    posisition = this.ClientSize.Width + rand.Next(500, 800) + (x.Width * 10);

                    x.Left = posisition;

                }
            }

            gameTimer.Start();

        }


    }
}
```

it tells me to add more details so the next part is just word spam. Sorry.

Comment: Please share code as text, not as a link to an image of text.

Comment: use property and implement  INotifyProperty Changed as assign an event that updates the speed

Comment: Can this question be reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method of implementing this. It uses nothing more than creating a `get-set property` that references a method that I named `OnScoreChanged()`.

```
int _score;
int speed;
private int score
{
    get
    {
        return _score;
    }
    set
    {
        _score = value;
        OnScoreChanged();
    }
}
```

And your OnScoreChanged() method can support the change of speed.

```
private void OnScoreChanged()
{
    speed++;
}
```

**Note** that this event is called whenever you change the value of `score`. To avoid increasing the `speed` when the `score` decreases, you can do something like the following:

```
private int score
{
    get
    {
        return _score;
    }
    set
    {
        if(_score < value)  // When the value of score increases
        {
            OnScoreIncreased();
        }
        else if(_score > value) // When the value of score decreases
        {
            OnScoreDecreased();
        }
        else
        {
            _score = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a stupid question but where do it inplement this in my code/program?

Comment: You can put them anywhere in the main hierarchy of the class.
I would recommend to put _score, speed and score near the top next to the other variables you have defined there.

The method OnScoreChanged() can be placed anywhere in the class just as you have with the other methods you wrote.